# Handling maximum request length exceeded in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Is there is a way to handle maximum request size exceeded in ASP.NET Core?

I am looking for a way to override the default behavior of ASP.NET Core which is to return HTTP 404 and instead I would like to return a custom response for calls to API methods that exceed maximum allowed size.

Comment: Hello, I am in search of this same solution. Have you found any solution to this in any way?